# How to populate columns with data in Excel using unique row combinations between two columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, advanced-filter

This seems like it should be easy enough to do, but I can't seem to figure it out or find a tutorial.

I have two columns containing values. I would like the unique column combinations to repeat in another set of columns, and count the instances.

```
COLUMN A COLUMN B             COLUMN C COLUMN D COLUMN E
John     Apples               John     Apples   2
John     Apples               John     Bananas  1
John     Bananas              Sara     Apples   1
Sara     Apples               Sara     Kiwi     1
Sara     Kiwi                 Mike     Carrots  2
Mike     Carrots              Mike     Kiwi     1
Mike     Carrots                       Apples   2
Mike     Kiwi                          Carrots  1
         Apples                        Kiwi     1
         Apples
         Carrots
         Kiwi
```

I was able to transfer the unique values from one column to another using `INDEX` and `MATCH`, but can't get it to work with two columns.

This tutorial shows what I am looking for, but I'd like the second set of data to stay in a column, and not transpose into rows. https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3358-excel-transpose-unique-values.html

Comment: You can't find a video on data, advanced filter on microsoft.com, office.com or youtube.com?

Comment: Good call — but I still can't get two columns -> two columns. Maybe I'm doing something wrong. I can get two columns -> one column, but not comparing them combined and transferring the combined as two separate columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following this short animated screen capture finishing with the following formula in E2.

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A, IF(LEN(C2), C2, ""), B:B, D2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!! That didn't seem to work the first time I tried it (or the second) ... But your example gave me the courage to persist and it worked. (I must've had a value set incorrectly.) Thank you so much!

Comment: Wouldn't a pivot table be easier to set up?

Comment: I need about the same time to create the table and pull the fields into the pivot table field list. It comes down to preference I guess. Pivot tables can be great for people who don't want to bother with formulae, and can be refreshed with one click. But you know all this, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is called a Pivot Table. Drag Name and Fruit into the rows area and Fruit again into the Values area to have it counted. Pivot tables can have different layouts, i.e. with repeating labels, or in compact format.

[image]

Comment: This is very useful. I almost added in my original question that I am not experienced with Pivot Tables or VBA. That said, the answer from @Jeeped is what I was looking for — the two columns must remain side by side, because there will be additional data reads on the area.

Comment: As I said, a pivot table can be configured to repeat the labels instead of using blank cells.